# Retrieving the logged in user's name and hostname in Windows

Tags: java, windows, unix, nt

I'm currently writing a Java application to be used with a Windows-Machine authed with an ActiveDirectory. The application basically only needs to know the user's name and hostname. I know there are

`System.getProperty("user.name")`

and

`java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()`

But I am not sure wether System.getProperty("user.name") will function correctly with the VM running on windows (I searched google and found a lot of threads saying it *might* not work with windows, as it might return something different, depending on the environment-variables
(and I am currently unable to test it [I'm running ubuntu and archLinux]).

So, I wondered if there is a better and more secure way to handle this and stumbled upon [NTSystem](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/security/jaas/spec/index.html) .
But NTSystem does not seem to be available on Linux (which I use for developing), which - I think - is due to calling native windows code.

My question would hence be: "Is there a secure way to retrieve the logged in user's name in Windows and if yes - how would you accomplish that?"

Comment: user.name should be platform independent, but run a test program and see it yourself.

Comment: But anyone can override it via -Duser.name=XYZ so it's inherently insecure

Comment: Do you mean "using Linux as my development environment" when you say "in Linux"? See my answer below for a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user.name` is **inherently insecure** because it can be overridden via `-Duser.name=XYZ`. This might be an issue for you, or it may not be

Obviously `NTSystem` won't work on Linux but you mention that you are writing a GUI to be run on Windows. Are you trying to validate the Windows user name of the user? You can do this via `NTSystem` embedded in *the code which runs on the Windows client* but **not** (of course) code which runs under the `Linux OS`.

Or are you trying to validate them on a Linux server? Perhaps you have a `kerberos` domain you could do this with? (i.e. if there is a `kerberos` domain, then you can have a secure, authenticated communication between client and server, ensuring that the client is who they say they are)

**EDIT**: *I may be confused by the fact you are saying that you're writing a Java App "in Linux". I took this to mean a Linux server and Windows client - but possibly you just mean that you are using Lenux as your development environment? In this case, you might think of writing a pluggable identification layer which you can switch between using `NTSystem` on the Windows box and `user.name` for testing*

Comment: Yes, Linux is my development environment.
I'm just trying to avoid the user.name property, as it is - as you said - inherently insecure.

(Actually the setup looks like this: Linux Server with Windows-Server-VirtualMachine(+ActiveDirectory), a bunch of Windows clients. I've got a java application running on the server, a c++ client running on all windows-machines and a java-client running on *certain* windows-machines. But I also want to avoid having to contact the AD/Windows-Server-VM)

Comment: Here's how I chose to do it:
I downloaded the windows java jdk and extracted com.sun.security.* from its libs. I then added them as a library to my project an imported NTSystem. In the app itself I check which OS it is running on to determine which System to use (either NTSystem or UnixSystem).

This could and can easily be avoided by having NTSystem and UnixSystem implement an interface which provides 'getUserName' and similar methods, so that you can use a more generic System (you could name it "GenericSystem" or "AbstractSystem" e.g.). Would be a nice addition to openJDK, I think ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [JNA](http://jna.dev.java.net/), com.sun.platform.jna.win32 has a number of methods to do this wrapping the Win32 API. Try Advapi32Util.getUserName or Kernel32Util.getUserNameEx.